# I'm stuck in a Pokemon room!

Tags: pokemon-global-revolution

I'm new to the whole Pokémon genre, but I'm playing a game called
"Pokémon Global Revolution". It's a re-make-ish of the original Pokémon games for the Nintendo Gameboy, but for the PC. I'm in Valerian City, and in a building that appears to be a school. I'm trying to go out, but it acts like the door is just a wall, and won't let me go out.

It's nighttime, so maybe the doors are locked? Can anyone solve this and tell me how to get out? I like this character and don't want to have to start a new save...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nevermind, turns out I was just forgetting to use the correct button.
Kinda embarrassed...

Comment: @aytimothy This is a complete answer.

Comment: "the right button"? As in "the *right mouse* button", or "the *correct* button"?

Comment: Correct button. My mistake.

Comment: Could you indicate the correct button to use?